# Windows - Sphinx configuration

Tags: php, sphinx

I've got a problem with sphinx configuration and php api use (on Windows 7).

I've configured the indexer : indexer --config sphinx.conf test1
And launch the service : searchd --install --config sphinx.conf
When I made a search with the cmd console, I found results, but... not with the php api.

Here the error : Query failed: failed to read searchd response (status=2613, ver=11830, len=774976045, read=70).

Here my conf file :

```
#
# Minimal Sphinx configuration sample (clean, simple, functional)
#

source src1
{
type            = mysql

sql_host        = localhost
sql_user        = root      
sql_pass        =
sql_db          = test
sql_port        = 3306  # optional, default is 3306

sql_query       = \
    SELECT id, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(addTime) AS addTime, title, brand, material, size, description, c.name as categoryName \
    FROM test \
    JOIN category c ON c.id = advert.categoryId


sql_attr_uint       = id
sql_attr_timestamp  = addTime

sql_query_info      = SELECT * FROM test WHERE id=$id
}


index catalog 
{
source          = src1
path            = C:\wamp\www\sphinx\catalog
docinfo         = extern
charset_type    = utf-8


min_word_len            = 3
min_prefix_len          = 0
min_infix_len           = 3
}

indexer
{
mem_limit       = 32M
}


searchd
{
listen          = 9312
listen          = 9306:mysql41
log             = C:\wamp\www\sphinx\log\searchd.log
query_log       = C:\wamp\www\sphinx\log\query.log
read_timeout        = 5
max_children        = 30
pid_file        = C:\wamp\www\sphinx\log\searchd.pid
max_matches     = 1000
seamless_rotate     = 1
preopen_indexes     = 1
unlink_old      = 1
workers         = threads # for RT to work
binlog_path     = C:\wamp\www\sphinx\data
}
```

The php file :

```
<?php
include('sphinxapi.php');

//Sphinx
$s = new SphinxClient;
$s->setServer("localhost", 3306);
$s->setMatchMode(SPH_MATCH_EXTENDED2);

$result = $s->query("@title jean");

if ($result['total'] > 0) {
foreach ($result['matches'] as $id => $otherStuff) {
        echo $id;
}
} else {
echo "Query failed: " . $s->GetLastError() . ".\n";  
}
```

?>

Answer (score 2):

You are pointed in php script 3306 - it's port of mysql server in line:

```
$s->setServer("localhost", 3306);
```

try to point port 9312

Also try do following steps:

1. Remove installed windows service.

   searchd --delete
2. Install windows service with full path to the configuration file

   searchd --install --config fullPathToSphinx.conf
3. You need to run service manually or restart PC. To start manually service: run from command line program `services.msc` and find in the services list `searchd` and start it.

Comment: Now, i've got this error : Query failed: connection to localhost:9312 failed (errno=10061, msg=Aucune connexion n’a pu être établie car l’ordinateur cible l’a expressément refusée.). (Sorry for the french...)

Comment: Did you updated config file to leave only port `listen=9312` and sphinx server was restarted?

Comment: Inccorrect. You CAN have multiple listen directive. Having both like that means will listen with sphinx API on 9312 and SphinxQL on 9306. But correct that setServer should be pointd to sphinxAPI port, not mysql :)

Comment: Thanks. Steps 1 & 2 are ok but at step 3 I've an error 1067, and the service is stopped..

Comment: And I can find the searchd.pid file !

Comment: Try to run from command line `searchd --install --config fullPathToSphinx.conf` but without `--install` option, so it will be `searchd --config fullPathToSphinx.conf`

Comment: Yes service is turned on ! But, I've got an other error : unknown local index 'sites' in search request

Comment: Try to restart searchd service.

Answer (score 1):

don't use "localhost" on Windows.

$s->setServer("127.0.0.1", 9312);